# Why does Maven not find/figure out the version of the artifact in the child pom?

Tags: java, maven

I am restructuring a projects and wonder why i need to specify the version of an artifact in a child when it should be known...

Just to give an overview before i get into the details.
I have the following:

A library called generalUtils.
It has a parent, bom and a few 'other' artifacts.
In it, each of the 'other' artifacts parent, is the parent artifact, whose parent is the bom artifact

A library called web.
It depends on the generalUtils library.
it has a parent, bom, and a few 'other' artifacts.
In it, each of the 'other' artifacts parent, is the parent artifact, whose parent is the bom artifact.
In the DependencyManagement.Dependencies section of the parent artifact, I import the generalUtils bom artifact

I don't have to specify the version of any of the generalUtils artifacts in project web. Everything is fine.

However...

I also have a library called monitor.
It depends on both the generalUtils and web libraries.
it has a parent, bom, and a few 'other' artifacts.
In it, each of the 'other' artifacts parent, is the parent artifact, whose parent is the bom artifact.
In the DependencyManagement.Dependencies section of the parent artifact, I import both the generalUtils and web bom artifacts.

I don't have to specify the version of any of the generalUtils artifacts in any of the project monitor artifacts. However, if i don't specify the version of any of the web project artifacts. i get an error message.

webApi is one of the artifacts in the web library project and i'm getting this error message:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 2 projects -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.retx.monitor:eventCollector:1.0.6.InSync (C:\TFSROOT\Monitor_1.0.6.In\EventCollector\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.retx.web:webAPI:jar is missing. @ line 74, column 15
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.retx.monitor:eventNotifier:1.0.6.In (C:\TFSROOT\Monitor_1.0.6.In\EventNotifier\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.retx.web:webAPI:jar is missing. @ line 78, column 15
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
...
```

It's complaining that in two of the 'other' artifacts in the monitor project (eventCollector and eventNotifier) i have not specified a version for a web library artifact (webAPI)

Why is it complaining only about the web artifact and not about the generalUtils artifacts even though they are import exactly in the same way?

I'm using maven 2.0.11 for generalUtils and web libraries, but the monitor library is built using maven 3.0.3.

Now the actual pom files:

Project library generalUtils bom artifact's pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.retx.general.utils</groupId>
  <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>bom</name>
  <description>Bill of Materials for general utils</description>

    <properties>
        <generalUtils.version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</generalUtils.version>

        <!-- wildfly third-party dependencies versions -->
    </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.retx.general.utils</groupId>
                <artifactId>configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${generalUtils.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- a few others similar to the above -->

    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>       
</project>
```

Project library web bom artifact's pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.retx.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>bom</name>
  <description>Bill of Materials for Web</description>

    <properties>
        <webRoot.version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</webRoot.version>

        <!-- bring in needed boms from other streams -->
        <generalUtils.version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</generalUtils.version>
    </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.retx.web</groupId>
                <artifactId>webApi</artifactId>
                <version>${webRoot.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- a few others similar to the above -->

    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Finally the monitor library artifacts, from parent down...

monitor library bom artifact pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.retx.monitor</groupId>
  <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.6.In</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>bom</name>
  <description>Bill of Materials for Monitor Modules</description>

    <properties>
        <!-- this stream -->
        <monitor.version>1.0.6.In</monitor.version>

        <!-- bring in needed boms from other streams -->
        <webRoot.version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</webRoot.version>           <!--  wildfly changed from 2.7.0.1-SNAPSHOT -->    
        <generalUtils.version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</generalUtils.version> <!-- wildfly changed from 1.0.2-SNAPSHOT -->

        <!-- wildfly third-party dependencies versions -->
        <!-- ... -->
    </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.retx.monitor</groupId>
                <artifactId>eventCollector</artifactId>
                <version>${monitorRoot.version}</version>
                <type>ejb</type>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.retx.monitor</groupId>
                <artifactId>eventNotifier</artifactId>
                <version>${monitorRoot.version}</version>
                <type>ejb</type>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

monitor library parent artifact pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns              = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi          = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                               http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.retx.monitor</groupId>
        <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6.In</version>
        <relativePath>bom/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>monitor-root</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>monitor-root</name>
    <description>Monitor Modules</description>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- import the generalUtils library bom -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.retx.general.utils</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>${generalUtils.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>   
            </dependency>

            <!-- import the web library pom -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.retx.web</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>${webRoot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>   
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                <version>${xalan.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- other third part dependencies ->

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <!-- the rest is not relevant ->
</project>
```

pom.xml of the eventCollector artifact in the monitor library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                               http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.retx.monitor</groupId>
        <artifactId>monitor-root</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6.In</version>
        <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.retx.monitor</groupId>
    <artifactId>eventCollector</artifactId>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>
    <name>EventCollector</name>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- dependency from the generalUtils library ->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.retx.general.utils</groupId>
            <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- dependency from the web library ->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.retx.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>webAPI</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- third party artifacts-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- other third party artifacts-->

    </dependencies>

    <!-- the rest is not important --> 
</project>
```

The relevant error message disappears if i just add the version to the webApi dependency in the above xml, like:

```
        <!-- dependency from the web library ->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.retx.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>webAPI</artifactId>
            <version>${webRoot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Shouldn't maven be able to deduce the version of webAPI from the info in the parent artifact?
(Note that the generalUtils dependency does not need the version to be specified here... )

Comment: Holy wall of text, Batman!

Comment: just to clarify... the question is "why i need to specify the version of an artifact in a child?" and NOT " why i need to specify the version of the child artifact?" The question more specifically relates to an artifact in an imported  BOM... asking why that artifact's version is not known in the child of the importer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is:

parent pom :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
  <artifactId>ear-example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>ear-example</name>
  <modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
    <module>module3</module>
  </modules>

  <dependencyManagement>
     <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
      </dependency>
     </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

Then in each of the children/modules you have a dependency with no version, i.e. the version is inherited from the parent :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
    <artifactId>ear-example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>example-war Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>example-war</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: i think that's a general answer to the topic of this question but not an answer to the questions in it :-)